# What is the title of a short story about a man searching for a holy man St. Anselm who turns out to be a robot?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a story in an anthology published in the 80s about a future where religion was illegal and a secret Christian was searching for the body of a holy man - maybe named Anselm, whose body was supposedly incorrupt, in order for the Catholic Church to declare him a saint.  He finds the body which turns out to be inccorupt because it is a robot.  And a meditation follows about the ability of the robot to reason so perfectly so as to come to believe in God.  Maybe the title was "The Search for St. Anselm" but this turns up nothing.  Thanks

Answer (score 16):

"[The Quest for Saint Aquin](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49806)" (1951) by Anthony Boucher.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quest_for_Saint_Aquin):

> In a post-apocalyptic technocratic future Earth, religion has been banned and the Catholic church has gone underground, relying on secret cells and symbols as in the days of the early church. The central character is a crypto-priest named Thomas who is charged by the secret pope with finding the resting place of a semi-legendary figure called Aquin (a hint to [Saint Thomas of Aquin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Aquinas)). Aquin had been an evangelist of great power who converted all those who listened to him preach, and his body supposedly never rotted after his death. The Pope believes that this miracle, if true, will be a powerful tool in winning new converts.

Comment: @LogicDictates, you edited a direct quote from wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the the source of the quote, and the revision history of this answer, you'll see that I did so in order to reverse another user's edit to the quote. I could've just used the rollback feature, which would've made my intentions clearer, but I wanted to make a couple of other tweaks to the answer, rather than just solely reversing the changes made by the other user. Also, the other user added a link to another Wikipedia page, which is present in the source of the quote, so I decided to let that stay.